# Fineuploader cancel upload after user response on file submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, fine-uploader

I am trying to get user response on file submit to cancel or not to cancel file upload but it doesn't seem to stop file upload may be I am missing something pls suggest

```
onSubmit: function(id, name) {
                    doc_status = $('#doc_attach_status').val(); 
                                if (doc_status == "true" ) {

                         if(confirm("Please note, if you upload a new PDF, old one will be replaced") == false){

                              manualuploader.cancelAll(); // tried but does not work    
                             cancelAll();// tried but does not work 
                             cancel(id);// tried but does not work 
                             $(this).cancelAll();// tried but does not work 
                             }

                    }

               },
```

And yes I am able to successfully upload files ......

And this is complete function I am using ...

```
var manualuploader = new qq.FineUploader({
            callbacks : {
                onComplete : function(id, name, response) {
                }
            },
            element : $('#pdf-fine-uploader')[0],
            request : {

                endpoint : "/UploadPdf",
                params : {
                    variant_id : $('#variant_id').val(),
                }
            },
            multiple : false,
            autoUpload : true,
            text : {
                uploadButton : '<i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> Select File </br> Maximum upload size less than 2 MB'
            },
            validation : {
                allowedExtensions : ['pdf', 'txt'],
                //sizeLimit: 51200, // 50 kB = 50 * 1024 bytes
                sizeLimit : 2097152//, // 2 MB = 2 * 1024 * 1024 bytes
                //itemLimit : 6
            },
            callbacks : {

                onSubmit: function(id, name) {
                    doc_status = $('#doc_attach_status').val(); 
                    // var answer = confirm("Please note, if you upload a new PDF, your current Tasting Notes PDF will be replaced");   
                    if (doc_status == "true" ) {

                         if(confirm("Please note, if you upload a new PDF, your current Tasting Notes PDF will be replaced") == false){

                              manualuploader.cancelAll();    

                             }

                    }

               },                   
                onComplete : function(id, fileName, responseJSON) {
                    if (responseJSON.success) {
                        $('.doc_link').html(responseJSON.docurl);
                        $('#doc_delete_link').addClass('icon-remove-sign');
                         $('.doc_description_head').show();
                         $('#doc_pdf_head').show();
                         $('.doc_description_div').show();
                         $('.description_save').show();
                          $('#doc_delete_link').show();
                    }
                }

            }

        });
        $('#triggerUpload').click(function() {
            manualuploader.uploadStoredFiles();
        });

    });
```

Comment: As the documentation states, you can return false in your onSubmit callback to ask Fine Uploader to ignore the associated file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got very simple solution ...

just use

retrun true or false after getting user response ....

```
onSubmit: function(id, name) {
                doc_status = $('#doc_attach_status').val(); 
                            if (doc_status == "true" ) {

                     if(confirm("Please note, if you upload a new PDF, old one will be replaced") == false){

                         retutn false;
                         }

                }

           },
```